# CONSTRUCT a subgraph in SPARQL with propertyPath of unknown length

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

I am trying to extract a subgraph from a large dataset (namely Wikidata, through their [Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org) ). I have found pairs of nodes that are of my interest (uses a certain property) and now I would like to `CONSTRUCT` a new graph, that would contain these pairs including a chain of properties and nodes, which joins them together (subclass chain).

So I have something like:

```
CONSTRUCT { #todo }
WHERE {
        ?s1 ex:p1 ?o1 .
        ?s2 ex:p2 ?o2 .
#OPTIONAL {?s1 rdfs:subClassOf* ?s2.} #something-like
}
```

Although, my actual query is a bit more complicated because I am also extracting different information from the same property (based on its string value), but it should not affect the problem.

Now I would like to copy the `propertyPaths` of `rdfs:subClassOf`, which joins those pairs, into the new graph. So I would like to put something like --

```
?s1 rdfs:subClassOf* ?s2 .
```

-- into the `CONSTRUCT{}` part but, of course, it's not allowed syntax.

Comment: That doesn't work, if you also need the intermediate nodes. Even with `?start :p+ ?mid .
  ?mid :p* ?end .` you would lose the information of the pairs.

Comment: By the way, the property is called **rdfs** `:subClassOf`

Comment: @AKSW thanks for the expected answer... :-/ And you are right, I corrected the subClassOf property in the original question, thanks.

Comment: @jmac, possibly you could figure out something using `?start :p* ?mid1 . ?mid1 :p ?mid2 . ?mid2 :p* ?end .`.

Comment: Also, `wdt:P279` is used on Wikidata instead of `rdfs:subClassOf`.